# CallableStatement, OUT parameters and passing non-JDBC parameter expressions as arguments - how does indexing work?

Tags: jdbc, stored-functions, callable-statement

The documentation seems very vague on the interaction of stored procedure's *OUT* parameters with various other JDBC features. Do I presume correctly, that index passed to a `registerOutParameter` method has to be the 1-based index of the procedure's parameter, and is not the same as the index of `PreparedStatement`'s parameter passed as the argument for that parameter? There is a potential for discrepancy/ambiguity when the argument for a procedure is a literal (or an SQL expression non-dependent on JDBC parameters), or when the argument expression depends on two JDBC parameters.

```
c.prepareCall("{? = call myfunc(?, 1, ?, ? + ?, 2)}")
```

1. In the example, if the last three parameters of the procedure are *IN/OUT* parameters, the indices that should be   registered are 1, 4, 5, 6 - correct?
2. If I switch to procedure syntax of `{call myfunc(?, 1, ?, ? + ?, 2)}`, they go down by one to 3, 4, 5 - correct?
3. By experimenting I found that cursor *OUT* parameters can be retrived by `(ResultSet) getObject(i)`, except when it is the return type of the function, in which case it becomes simply 'statement.getResultSet`. Is this behavior vendor independent?
4. If a `CallableStatement` is batched, can *OUT* parameters be retrieved at all? If so, are the results of only the last execution available?

Comment: Re question 1, the index used by `registerOutParameter` is the index of the `?` placeholder.  Also,  if the last three parameters of your function `myfunc` are `OUT` parameters, then your database will report an error attempting to call your function as above.  Suppose the value 7 is to be returned in the second-from-last parameter of `myfunc`: how should this be split across the two `?` placeholders whose value you are adding up?

Comment: That's why I assumed that out parameters are independent of JDBC out parameters - the value would not be split, but returned as a parameter with index 4 (or 3 in the procedure call syntax). If the indices used for out parameters are the same as statement parameters, then it would imply that in fact '?' are the only 'expressions' allowed in a `CallableStatement`, excluding even literals as parameters?

Comment: Literals and expressions can be used for IN parameters, but IN parameters only.  For an OUT or an IN OUT parameter, you must use a single placeholder alone.  For example, If you have `{? = call myfunc(14, 987, 'XYZ', ?)}`, then there are only two `?` placeholders.  If the first three parameters of `myfunc` are IN parameters and the last one is an OUT parameter, you would use `.registerOutParameter(2, ....)` to set up the last OUT parameter.